# Huawei AREngine C++

Tags: c++, augmented-reality, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to access to the Time Of Flight sensor, in order to use the data. In the Huawei AR Engine documentation I found the following function :

```
HwArPointCloud_getData(ar_session, ar_point_cloud, &point_cloud_data);
```

The point_cloud_data is an array of float composed by (x,y,z and the confidence) But I don't know how I can parse it?

Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as Thinking that each float number is divided in (x | y | and DEPTH16)

It's not. It'd make no sense. A float has a certain format, that's what makes it a float. If you start "dividing" it, it's not a float, but maybe an `int` bitfield or something, but not a float. So forget about that line of thinking. It's much simpler than that.

It's consecutive floats. How many different ways could you think of to represent such data, if you were a time-crunched Huawei engineer? :) It's highly likely you'll figure it out in one or two tries. Try displaying it assuming it goes `x,y,z,conf` then `conf,x,y,z`. The permutations of `x,y,z` coordinates are also easy to untangle. While the documentation apparently is beyond contempt, it's not a very hard puzzle to solve. Visualizing the data is the key, though. Looking at those numbers as numbers will bore you soon.

Note that you're not supposed to "parse" anything. This is a simple `const float *array`. Just read it as if it was an array of floats, four floats per point. The C++ standard also lets you treat it as an array of structs of floats, to make your life easier:

```
struct Point {
  float x, y, z, confidence;
};
...
const Point *point_cloud_data = {};
...
HwArPointCloud_getData(ar_session, ar_point_cloud, 
                       reinterpret_cast<const float**>(&point_cloud_data));
```